# Programmatic equivalent of 'copy figure' menu action

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am developing a Matlab GUI application that plots a figure with additional UI elements in the GUI window. I would like to add a menu action to the GUI window menu that exactly duplicates the standard figure window menu's "Edit|Copy Figure" entry, so that the copy figure options 'preserve information', 'force white background', and 'match figure screen size' can be applied.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

**EDIT To add what worked**

Rather than trying to copy/modify/paste the code in the figure window menu handler, I just called it from the GUI menu function

```
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function CopyFigureMenuItem_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to CopyFigureMenuItem (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
editmenufcn(handles.figure1, 'EditCopyFigure');
```

Almost certainly not future-proof, and not guaranteed to work in any future version, but in R2014a it does what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type

```
>>edit editmenufcn
```

at Matlab command prompt to see all the programmatic invocations  of the Edit Menu. Apparently what you are looking for is:

```
editmenufcn(hFigure, 'EditCopyFigure');
```

Of course, `hFigure` should be the handle of the figure that you want copied.

**Later edit**

Peeking into the code might give you hints to implement more refined functionalities. The body of the function is a huge `switch` statement; looking for `'EditCopyFigure'` string will give you the code snippet that you're interested in. Be careful not to modify this function, or to save changes, though. :-)

However, this function is undocumented and might be changed/removed in later versions. I hope you are not bothered by this.

<s>**Even later edit**</s>

Apparently the above is not the answer to the question. The answer would be *"Yes, there is at least one who knows how to do this."* :-)